# Understanding Objective in OpenAI InstructGPT paper?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, sampling, reinforcement-learning, kullback-leibler

The following objective is taken from the paper ['Training language models to follow instructions with human feedback'](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.02155):[image]which is used to fine-tune the pre-trained language model using Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO). In the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06347), the objective of PPO is as follows: [image]comparing the two objectives we can see the term with beta in equation 2 must be the KL term in equation 5.

Now there was a previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/606769) here.

NO ML/RL is really needed.

$\pi_\phi^{\mathrm{RL}}= \pi_\theta\left(a_t \mid s_t\right)$ and $\pi_\phi^{\mathrm{SFT}}= \pi_{\theta old}\left(a_t \mid s_t\right)$

---

My question is different as I don't quite understand how the KL terms are equivalent.

As If we take the InstructGPT objective and isolate the KL part we have

$E_{(x, y) \sim D_{\pi_\phi^{\mathrm{RL}}}}\left[-\beta \log \left(\pi_\phi^{\mathrm{RL}}(y \mid x) / \pi^{\mathrm{SFT}}(y \mid x)\right)\right]$ = $-\beta E_{(x, y) \sim D_{\pi_\phi^{\mathrm{RL}}}}\left[\log \left(\pi_\phi^{\mathrm{RL}}(y \mid x) / \pi^{\mathrm{SFT}}(y \mid x)\right)\right]$ = $-\beta \mathrm{KL}(\pi_\phi^{\mathrm{RL}} | \pi^{\mathrm{SFT}})$

While the term in the PPO equation is effectively $-\beta \mathrm{KL}(\pi^{\mathrm{SFT}} |\pi_\phi^{\mathrm{RL}} )$ ?

Comment: I would say that there is not much in common between them... $r_\theta$ in PPO is the importance sampling ratio, here is the actual reward given by the reward model..

Comment: 1. The link to the 'previous question' in the post is broken.
2. Agree that the objective in InstructGPT is weird and not clear. The most important part, which is the ratio of new policy to the old policy, multiplied by the Advantage, is missing. so the only trainable term is in the KL divergence, and that feels like a bug.
3. I also think they replaced by mistake the order of terms in the KL term.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the PPO objective equation is incorrect in the paper, it should be

−KL(SFT|RL)

as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: Hi, this answer can be improved by editing it to provide a justification or explanation.

Comment: Besides this bug in the equation of the InstructGPT paper, what about the missing expression of the advantage?